# bind_param error in PHP: "number of variables doesnt match number of parameters"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bindparam

I am well aware this question has been asked before and I am really sorry for asking again, but the others didn't answer it for my situation. I have no idea what could be wrong with this bind_param. Here is the code for my PHP:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "HIDDEN", "HIDDEN", "HIDDEN");
if ($db->connect_error) {
   die("Sorry, there was a problem connecting to our database.");
}

$username = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']));

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages");
$result->bind_param("s", $username);
$result->execute();

$result = $result->get_result();
while ($r = $result->fetch_row()) {
   echo $r[1];
   echo "\\";
   echo $r[2];
   echo "\n";
}
```

What could be wrong with this bind_param? Sorry to bother again and thanks for the help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain *how* the other questions did not answer this for you. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: sidenote: you don't need this `stripslashes(htmlspecialchars` since you're using prepared statements. the 2nd function is mostly used for displaying.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Sorry I am new to PHP so I would just like to thank you guys for being so friendly.

Comment: I have my own assumptions as to why your code is failing, but I can't say for certain since there are a few unknowns here.

Comment: It's fine man thanks for the help on the stripslashes/htmlspecialchars though!

Comment: problem solved then, okilie dokilie! Great news, I am moving on... *ciao!*

Comment: Your question must have had the bar raised just high enough then ! Or, ah, I don't know what I am saying.

Comment: @Drew I for one was never into gymnastics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are trying to bind variable `s` here `$result->bind_param("s", $username);`.

Problem is that you are not using it in your query.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand what I am supposed to do here. Do I get rid of the "s"? I am very confused.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `placeholders` (question marks, `?`) in your prepare statement, and the number of parameters for `bind_param` method should be 1+num of `?` symbols.

first argument represent the data type of the arguments, followed by the bind parameter values.

In your example you are passing 2 params to your bind_param method (first param, `s` represents string and 2nd param, `$username` represents the value.), but there is no placeholder `?` in your query.